# Export to Excel is slow

Tags: 2010, 2013, excel, performance, export

I am working with SharePoint 2010 / 2013. Very often I have to export large lists (>1000 Items) to Excel. This always takes some time (e.g. about 3 Minutes for 3500 list items).

Is this normal, or should I check my SP-Farm?

Is there any way to speed this up?

Comment: One way to speed things up would be do make a view and filter out/include only the list items and columns that you require and make an export to excel with that view applied, instead of grabbing all list items and removing/filter in excel.

Comment: You could measure your farm performance while exporting to excel using fiddler as well. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler